# Android handler as a timer not accurate

Tags: android, timer, handler, delay, sleep

I'm using Handler to send message every 10 seconds. The problem occurs when I turn off the screen (device goes to sleep mode). Messages are sent every 30 sec - 2 mins instead of every 10 seconds. Why is this happening? How to resolve this problem?

```
public void PingTask() {        
    handler = new Handler();        
    runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                sendMSG("ping");
            } catch (Exception e) {}
            handler.postDelayed(this, 10000);
        }
    };
    runnable.run();
}
```

PingTask() is called from AsyncTask - onPostExecute().

Comment: Without looking at some of your code it's close to impossible to tell :) Post as much as you can.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android is turning off your CPU. Use [WakeLock](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.WakeLock.html) to prevent your device from turning into some kind of sleep mode.

You could also use an [alarmmanager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) to send a message every second. An Alarm manager automatically prevents your device from turning into sleep mode.

Comment: Note that if he needs precision, alarm manager is NOT the way to go. 
"Note: Beginning with API 19 (KITKAT) alarm delivery is inexact: the OS will shift alarms in order to minimize wakeups and battery use. There are new APIs to support applications which need strict delivery guarantees; see setWindow(int, long, long, PendingIntent) and setExact(int, long, PendingIntent). Applications whose targetSdkVersion is earlier than API 19 will continue to see the previous behavior in which all alarms are delivered exactly when requested."

Answer (score 1):

I also saw the same thing that neither handler or timer gave me an accurate delay, e.g. putting 6000 milliseconds delay will give me a delay between 500-7000 milliseconds delay, which is quite annoying.

Using wake lock may use too much battery. So here I have a helper class with the time it supposed to run, use postAtTime instead and re-post itself. It can easily handle more complicated schedule of different tasks at variable interval.

```
public void PingTask() {  
    /** here is how to use it */
    IntervalTask task = new IntervalTask();
    task.run();
}

class IntervalTask implements Runnable{
long runAtTime = 0;
Handler handler = new Handler();

public void run(){
    /** According to documentation, it uses uptimeMillis */
    long currentTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();

    /** only do it if it is time */
    if (currentTime > runAtTime){
        /** update it */
        runAtTime = currentTime + 10000;

        /** do you what you want to do here */
        sendMSG("ping");
    }

    handler.postAtTime(this, runAtTime);
}
}
```

Comment: This doesnt help, if you check AOSP source code, you see that handler.postDelayed(...) just calls handler.postAtTime(...), so it's the same thing.